# Handling user authorisation with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, .net-4.0, silverlight-5.0

When creating a new Silverlight 5.0 business application, the authentication and authorization code is automatically generated. All the user info and roles are by default saved in the aspnetdb mdf file. My questions are:

1. Is it normal practice to keep user authorization/authentication data in separate database from your business related data, or should I copy the tables into my main database? I see that current implementation involves `ApplicationId` field, so it means that it can store data for different apps? Maybe there is some common database on the web server for all Web apps (just guessing)? :)
2. If I am to keep the user's info in a separate database, how to relate the data between these two databases? I mean, I will have `UserId` referenced in some tables (business rules)? My business data is using identity PKs and aspnetdb is using UniqueIdentifier, is this a problem?
3. When a user registers on the site, how do we assign it roles in production? There is a ASP.NET Configuration tool within Visual Studio, but what about the production environment? Should this be coded in the Web project?
4. What is the best practice for handling authorization / authentication of users in cases where the application always require authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the defaut ASP.NET authentication implementation in your production App: It uses a local database (the mdf file) because it works out of the box. However, You are not limited by this solution:

- You could configure ASP.NET authentication (and role) provider to use your real database, allowing you to better integrate it into your existing data. To better understand the full process, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t.aspx and the linked pages. ASP.NET is able to generate all the required tables in your db by itself.
- You could override the default authentication mechanism with your own. In this case you only have to edit the Services/AuthenticationService.cs in your web app project. The AuthenticationService class inherits from AuthenticationBase, and allows you to override quite a lot of membership methods with you own implementations.